# Java usage() method

Tags: java

Hi Stackoverflow community

I have been trying to find a resource or reference that explains what the usage() method does. Unfortunately the word 'usage' is indexed so often in different contexts that I simply can't find a good resource. Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            usage(); 
        } else if ("parse".equals(args[0])) {
            final String[] parseArgs = new String[args.length - 1];
             etc ....
```

I know that in C getusage() is used to get memory and CPU usage statistics. Is this the same case in Java? Any pointers would be highly appreciated. 
Mike

Comment: This method is very likely to be in your code and will print out an error message as you have not provided any runtime arguments when some are expected.

Comment: there is no usage() inbuilt method in java. this method seems to be specific to your application.

Comment: There are **command line options** libraries that might provide as an extra a usage function, though that would need to be localized. Search those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usage()` **is not** a built in Java function. Your post includes an invocation that is presumably intended to display information about command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**usage** is not coming from any library or so.

Typically, such methods are written to print "how to use this tool" information for command line tools; upon user running the tool with "-h", "--help"; or after he provided invalid / missing command line arguments.
In other words: the person who created that main class/method ... also wrote the usage method.

In that sense: this is a good opportunity for you to learn how to navigate your java source code. Simply **search** for the declaration of this method to understand what it is doing!